# Size of document increases on iOS device compare to the Android/Windows device

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimage

There is one very interesting issue I face at the moment in my iOS application.

The image size got increased by the random number of percentage.

What I have observed is as below

[image: Mac OS file sizes]

When I choose the same image from the photo library and try to send the image by converting it to data, though the multipart form data API.

The image size also got increased in multiple times of the original image size.

I use the below code to convert the image into data bytes

> img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)

The data length is around 90 MB.
 
The original image is available [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg).
Does anyone know where is the issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: The preview images displayed in your screenshots are not alike, hence suggesting that you compare two totally different images here...

Comment: @Lutz the above image is for two files one is JPEG and one is PDF in windows or Android system. Below one is the same files screenshot for Mac OS. I'm not comparing them side by side but the above whole image is compared with below image comparatively.

Comment: Both sets of files look exactly the same number of bytes to me.  What is the issue?

Comment: @TheiOSDev If you don't compare side by side, then what's the problem? The sizes are exactly the same, aren't they? Maybe I don't understand the issue? Could you try to rephrase?

Comment: The issue here is that when I try to get that image using the photo library and convert it to Data for sending it in one of the API which accepts the image as multipart form data the image size in MB is around 90 MB that is the issue with me. Why the image size increases that much? around 900% increase in size when I convert the image into Data using code `img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)`